# Text is not shown when a filled rectangle is drawn

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I am drawing a table. First draw background and column grid line. I use the following `PrintRectangle` method to draw row background for alternative rows. Then drawing text to each column and each row. The issue is the text are not shown once the row background drawn. If I don't draw row background, then text is shown. Any idea what did I do wrong?

```
context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
context.ScaleCTM(1, -1);

void DrawText(string text, string fontName, int fontSize)
{
    using (var font = new CTFont(fontName, fontSize))
    {
        var attributes = new CTStringAttributes
        {
            ForegroundColorFromContext = true,
            Font = font         
        };
        using (var attributedString = new NSAttributedString(text, attributes))
        using (var textLine = new CTLine(attributedString))
        {
            textLine.Draw(context);
        }
    }
}

void DrawRect(CGRect rect, UIColor fillColor) 
{
   using (NSAutoreleasePool _autoReleasePool = new NSAutoreleasePool())
   {
     var path = new CGPath();
     path.AddRect(rect);

     context.AddPath(path);
     context.SetFillColor(fillColor.CGColor);
     context.DrawPath(CGPathDrawingMode.Fill);
   }
}
```

Comment: Show us the calling code.